# Cannot send parse push notification to other devices

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

The following is my cloud code to send parse push notification:

```
    Parse.Cloud.define('push1', function(response) 
{ 
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);

    Parse.Push.send
    ({
        where: query,
        data: 
        {
            alert: "Hai everyone..!!"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        useMasterKey : true,
        success: function() 
        {
            response.success("true");
        },
        error: function(error) 
        {
            response.error("error");
        }
    });
});
```

But the device from which I call this function only receives the notification. No other devices receives it.  There are 3 devices added to the Installation class.

this is the app code from which I call this function

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("push1", params, new FunctionCallback<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void done(String ratings, ParseException e)
                    {
                        if (e == null)
                        {
                            System.out.println("WORKED: " + ratings);
                        }
                        else
                            System.out.println(e.toString());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Give some more info about your question?

Comment: when i run my app on a device, only that device gets the notifications and it gets multiple notifications. no other devices gets any notification.

Comment: check parse-server log how many pushes were send actually

Comment: actually 5 pushes were send. and the device on which I run the app, keep receiving all those notifications.